# CakePHP Auth keeps redirecting me

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

Hi I have loaded the auth component and included the following;

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow('register', 'verify');
}
```

If I navigate to register it works correctly, however, if I go to verify it redirects me to login?

Any ideas?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public

Comment: To be clear, you need to pass the arguments as an array; `allow` takes only a single argument.

Comment: Of course it does - thank you the two of you!